# Can I force Google Chrome to download Salesforce Image Attachments?

Tags: attachment, chrome

Whenever I click View or Download on an Attachment in Salesforce, if it's an image, it simply previews the image in my browser.  For every other file type, I get the usual file download.

Is this a browser setting that I can change?

Answer (score 1):

you can control Download behavior in salesforce Settings

[File Upload and Download Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VFJo.png)

Comment: Thanks Autodidact, however you can't add your own filetypes to that list and it doesn't provide any image extensions unfortunately.